# Segmentation fault 11 for function naming in protocol extension

Tags: swift, function, segmentation-fault, protocol-extension

The problem is really simple. This causes a segmentation fault:

```
extension Sequence {

    func parallelForEach<T, R>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> R, completion: @escaping ([R]) -> ()) where Iterator.Element == T {
    }

}
```

Clearly I don't know how to write a protocol extension anymore. Someone help please? :)

Comment: A segmentation fault during compilation or execution?

Comment: Compilation. Sorry I didn't know the latter was possible.

Comment: If the compiler is crashing it's a bug no matter what.  You should definitely file a radar so Apple can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error was me thinking that I needed the generic type T. Since it was just Iterator.Element which is happily a type within the Sequence protocol.

```
extension Sequence {

    func parallelForEach<T, R>(_ f: @escaping (Iterator.Element) -> R, completion: @escaping ([R]) -> ()) {
    }

}
```

Kudos to anyone who can explain *why* the compiler didn't like it. It's clearly inefficient but why should it be wrong?